# Structure of the pre-Lie ring

Tags: ra.rings-and-algebras, noncommutative-rings

I am having difficulty understanding the following result from an article:

**Theorem**: Let $(A, +, .)$ be a pre-Lie ring with
$(A, +) \cong \mathbb{Z}/p^3\mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}$ generated by $x$ and $y$ as an additive group with $p^3x=py=0$. Also $A$ is generated by $x$ as a pre-Lie ring. Define $A^{i+1}=\sum_{j=1}^{i}A^j.A^{i+1-j}$. Given that $A^i=0$ for all $i \geq 3$. Then $(A^2,+)$ is generated by $p^2x$.

**Proof**: Let $y=ax+bx^2$ where $a,b \in \{1,\dotsc,p^3\}$. Note $A^2=\mathbb{Z}(x^2)$. So $(A^2,+)$ is generated by a single element. As $x$ generates $A$, $x \notin A^2$. So $(A^2,+)$ is either generated by $px$ or by $p^2x$. If $px$ generates $(A^2,+)$, then $\lvert(A^2,+)\rvert=p^2$. Now $px^2=px.x=0$ this implies $\lvert(A^2,+)\rvert=p$, a contradiction.
So $(A^2,+)$ is generated by $p^2x$.

My question is why we are assuming that $(A^2,+)$ is generated by $px$ or $p^2x$. If $\lvert (A^2,+)\rvert=p^2$, then it is generated by some element of the form $kpx+by$ where $p$ does not divide $k$. Are we rebranding the element as $px$? I am not getting any idea what is going on. If we assume that $(A^2,+) \cong \langle px\rangle \cong \langle kpx+by\rangle$ and proceed with $px$ will I get an isomorphic pre-Lie ring?

Also if  $\lvert(A^2,+)\rvert=p$, why $y$ is not chosen as generator? It may happen $y=x^2.$

This theorem can be found in the article [Puljić - Classification of braces of cardinality $p^4$](https://arxiv.org/abs/2211.04235) (Proposition $3.6$).

Comment: It seems that the initialization "$A^1=A$" is missing from your inductive definition in the theorem.

Comment: This is not true. The law given by $x^2=y$, $xy=yx=y^2=0$, satisfies $A^3=0\neq A^2=\mathbf{Z}y$. It seems you're pointing to the error.

Comment: (Pre-Lie is a distraction here: every [non-necessarily-associative] ring $A$ with $A^3=0$ is pre-Lie — and also Lie, associative, etc.)

Comment: Yes, that is my point. I was thinking whether the two pre-lie rings we are getting are isomorphic. But I have not been able to prove that either.

Comment: Also I was wondering when $|A^2|=p^2$, why it is assumed $A^2$ is generated by $px$? Again is it upto isomorphism?

Comment: You wrote "$A^2$ is either generated by $px, p^2x$." Based on the later text, I assumed that meant "$A^2$ is generated either by $p x$ or by $p^2 x$", and edited accordingly. \\ Markdown note: please use **Proof** `**Proof**`, not $\textbf{Proof}$ `\textbf{Proof}`. TeX note: please use $\langle p x\rangle$ `\langle p x\rangle`, not $<px>$ `<px>`.  E.g., compare the spacing in $\langle p x\rangle \cong <px> \cong \langle p x\rangle$ `\langle p x\rangle \cong <px> \cong \langle p x\rangle`.  I have edited accordingly for both of these.